# How many Emails can i send/receive in a day with Zoho mail lite subscription

Tags: zoho

I have purchased the mail lite subscription for 1 user which is the super admin user.

How many emails can i send in a day with my mail lite plan.

Comment: I’m closed this because the only way to answer this is to get an answer from the company itself.  Either it is going to be published on their website, or you will have to contact their customer service.  This requires inside knowledge about their policies.  There is no way that this can be answered without asking them.  If it isn't on their site, you should ask them yourself rather than asking here.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at their site, it doesn't look like there are any limits.  What makes you think there are?

Comment: I was searching and i came across this . https://help.zoho.com/portal/en/kb/crm/connect-with-customers/email/articles/email-limits#Limits_for_Individual_Emails

Maybe that is for zoho crm?. I am not using zoho crm. i am just using zoho mail.